# Using SVM output as binary classifier input

Tags: r, classification, svm, multi-class

For a certain document multi-class classification problem, I am experimenting with training an SVM in logistic regression mode (using `liblinear`). While the resulting classifier has a proven accurate, the log loss rate has proven to be too high (the probabilities between classes seemed not well calibrated).

To improve the logloss, I created a supplementary binary classifier (specifically `GLMBoost`, a boosted GAM) training against whether or not the prediction was accurate or inaccurate and using the class probabilities from the SVM as inputs. Using the resulting probabilities for each predicted class label, the logloss improved.

As I have not seen this approach used before, is this the right approach? Are there potential downsides to this approach that I should be aware of?